# How to return -1 in method

Tags: java

I am getting frustrated becuase the method would not take the return of -1 because of the else. I try creating a loop but still giving me issue of returning -1. I want the -1 to return only if when the user input an negative number. How do I do this?

If the input is negative, then the method returns -1

```
 public static int tringularNum(int num){
    int num1 = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    //Sum calculations
    if (num > num1){
        System.out.print("(");
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
            sum += i;
            System.out.print(i+ "+");
        }
        System.out.print(")");
        System.out.print(" = " + sum);
    }
    // Returns -1 if user enter a negative input
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your code needs a return inside the if(){} and ... it works. It does return -1 if the user enters -1. -> try it online: https://repl.it/Dlqe

Comment: Consider what should happen if input = 0. Return -1 also?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your method above your current code:

```
if(num < 0)
    return -1;
```

This will check if `num` is less than 0 and return -1 without continuing to the rest of your method code.

Comment: What if user enter -3, I want to let the user know that when he enters an negative number it return -1